# What does cin.get() do with no arguments?

Tags: c++, string, cin

What does `cin.get()` do when no arguments are passed?

Without the second `cin.get` call (line 13), my code doesn't work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[3][10];
    for (int i=0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cin.get(s[i], 9);
        cin.get();
    }
    cout << s[1];
    getch();
}
```

Comment: See, for instance, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: For future questions: *'doesn't work'* is usually far too imprecise to help you out of trouble. You should provide us the test input as well as expected output (if providing an [mre] we'd get actual output ourselves, so that's optional).

Comment: Assuming you have input `012345678901234567890123456789` then you should read `012345678` into the first sub-array, then skip the `9` (you do not catch the return value) and restart with next zero, so output would be `012345678` from second sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

The function `cin.get()` read a character from the istream `cin`. You may consider some cases.

case 1. Without `cin.get()`

```
 for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
       cin.get(s[i],9);
    }
```

This will work if you type all three strings`s[0]`, `s[1]`, and`s[2]` in a line without newline interupt.

```
123456789123456789123456789
```

This will result `s[0] = s[1] = s[2] = "123456789"`

Case 2. with `cin.get()`

The code will read one more character intending to read the newline `'\n'`. But it may fail if the input is more that 9 characters but less than 27 characters (case 1). `cin.get()` will read an extra character and leaving the `'\n'` into the next `s[i]` cause cin error.

Case 3. Suggest method

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
   {
       cin.get(s[i],9);
       cin.ignore(65536,'\n');
   }
```

Instead of reading one extra character, your may ignore all characters before `'\n'`. This is save for the above cases.